# Bootstrap Radio Button uncheck by jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with my code using the bootstrap plugin. 
I have some radio buttuns in the following code:

```
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Radio 1 (preselected)
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio 3
  </label>
   </div>
```

I want to put a button to reset the selection. I've tried a reset button (`<button type="reset">`), jQuery commands, but all fail.

In the Bootstrap API I found an explanation:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio

that says:

> Visual checked state only updated on click If the checked state of a
>   checkbox button is updated without firing a click event on the button
>   (e.g. via  or via setting the checked property of
>   the input), you will need to toggle the .active class on the input's
>   label yourself.

Please someone could help me find a solution to my problem?

Thanks, 
Gabriel.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, you need to remove active class from label tag, then make the properties checked element on radio into false state, try this simple example below :

```
$('button').click(function () {
  $('.btn-group').find('label').removeClass('active')
  .end().find('[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/94ae9j0e/)**

Comment: Thank you so much! Saved my job... :D

Comment: How can I do it without an extra button?

Comment: @Dejell What do you mean by that? Button click is just an example here, you can make it happen by just placing those code outside click event

Comment: I tried. look at this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/deligeli/gqf23tmw/ but it doesn't work :(

Comment: @Dejell you meant, you want to reset the button on page load? without clicking reset button?

Comment: no, I want to reset it on clicking. click on the selected button

Answer (score 3):

```
$("button").on('click', function() {
    $("input:radio").prop('checked', false);
    $("input:radio").closest("label").removeClass("active");
})
```

This jQuery code should help you. When you click a button, it removes the checked property from all radios and toggles the class of the label as the API says

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a button with id "reset" and add use jQuery to remove the `active` class?

```
$("#reset").click( function() {
    $(".btn").each( function() {
        this.removeClass("active");
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Add Button.prototype.toggle in bootstrap.js line 225

```
if ($input.prop('type') == 'radio' && !changed) {
    this.$element.removeClass('active');
    $input.prop('checked', false).trigger('change');
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't advise making direct changes to a lib. What happens when another developer updates the lib?